# How to display datas from two different tables into one by merging datas with same id into one row?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to display content of two table into one , one table is containing product details and another one images or the product details , Im uploading more than on image for a single product . i want o display it like, if there are 3 images for  one product then three images should be displaying as same row with product details.
How can i do that?

Table 1

```
id  pname   prodes  cat sucat   
76  bsb sbfb    fbfb    fdbfdb  
77  gripperr    black slim 7    pen ball pen    
78  technotip   black slim 7    pen ball pen    
79  gripperr    blue ink    rtnrtn  ball pen    
80  gripperr    blue ink    rtnrtn  ball pen    
82  vfdv    fdb fdbdf   bdfbdfb
```

Table 2

```
id  pid image   
4   76  1.jpg   
5   76  2.jpg   
6   76  3.jpg   
7   77  a.jpg   
8   77  b.jpg   
9   77  c.jpg   
10  78  img_20171004_064140-1547183108.jpg  
11  78  img_20171008_110354-1547183108.jpg  
12  78  v-1547183108.jpg    
13  79  aegi-1547183474.jpg 
14  79  b-1547183474.jpg    
15  79  c-1547183474.jpg    
16  80  aegi-1547183595.jpg 
17  80  b-1547183595.jpg    
18  80  c-1547183595.jpg    
20  82  yg-1547186213.jpg   
21  82  yoongi-1547186213.jpg
```

i want it like

```
id  pname   prodes  cat sucat   
76  bsb sbfb    fbfb    fdbfdb                    1.jpg   2.jpg  3.jpg
77  gripperr    black slim 7    pen ball pen  a.jpg   b.pjp  c.jpg  
78  technotip   black slim 7    pen ball pen    
79  gripperr    blue ink    rtnrtn  ball pen    
80  gripperr    blue ink    rtnrtn  ball pen    
82  vfdv    fdb fdbdf   bdfbdfb
```

Comment: Hi, show me your query.

Comment: i tried using inner joinbut i can't display it like that it just display as diferent rows

Comment: $sql= "SELECT * FROM product INNER JOIN images  ON product.id = images.pid";

Comment: I have given an answer. please check

Answer (score 1):

You can't make different amount of columns but can join all images separated by comma with mysql function group_concat

```
select t1.*, group_concat(t2.image) as images
from table1 as t1
left join table2 as t2 on t1.id=t2.pid
```

Answer to comment

You need one more loop, something as

```
foreach(explode(',', $row['image'] as $url) {
   $imageURL = 'pictures/'.$url;
   echo '<img src="<?php echo $imageURL; ?>" alt="" width="100" height="100" />'
}
```

Comment: i tried this and Notice: Undefined index: image i this is showing for me..image is the field in table two...

Comment: I've  named list of images as `images` so you  should use it as index in row `$row['images`

Comment: Or rename in query `select t1.*, group_concat(t2.image) as image`

Comment: okkk i edited it but now image is displaying there :( error is gone now

Comment: now its only displaying for one value ... only one row is there

Comment: foreach($result as $row)
{
 ?>
 <tr>
  <td><?php 
  $iid=$row['id'];
  echo $iid;
     ?>
  </td>
  <td><?php echo $row['pname'];?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['prodes'];?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['cat'];?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['sucat'];?></td>
  
  <td><?php $imageURL = 'pictures/'.$row['image'];?>
  <img src="<?php echo $imageURL; ?>" alt="" width="100" height="100"  /></td>

Comment: i add one more loop for displaying image?

Answer (score 0):

=> try this:-

Use left join get the left table all data and the matched records from the right table.

```
$sql= "select P1.*, group_concat(I2.image) images
    from product P1
    left join images I2 on P1.id=I2.pid";
```

Comment: i tried something similar to this now... but its only showng one row now... only one input's value

Comment: Do you run in MySQL?

Comment: use foreach ($result as $value) {
                                  print_r($value);
                                 } 
                                 exit;